# SQL Server 2014 modified date trigger for all tables

Tags: sql-server

I have approximately 15 tables that all have a column titled "modifieddate" and i want to create a trigger that will update that date upon record update. is there a way to do that with one trigger or do I need multiple ones? i also could use the code to do so as i am struggling with it.

I have tried the code but it does not work.

Comment: What code have you tried?  You can update muliple tables with a trigger, but I am not sure you should...

Comment: You will have to create a trigger for each table, there is no way around that. You could do it in your client code but a trigger is better because there is no way around it, it will always happen no matter what

Comment: Why do you need to update all of the table's modified date?  You can always select the max modified date joining all of the tables for each id to get a last modified date.  Updating all of the tables is actually removing data as you don't know downstream, which table was actually modified last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger on each table would work, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_update_trigger]
       ON [dbo].[Customers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.Customer
    SET ModfiedDate = GETDATE()     

END
```

However, you might want to put the logic in the application instead. For example, if you look at GETDATE() above, it isn't very flexible. The application would allow more flexibility.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need an "INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON customer.ID = i.ID" ?